# Setup Apache local testing server via Dreamweaver

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

It took me all day to find what is happening; however, I found nothing.I am using Dreamweaver CS6. I want to set up a local Apache testing server as to run .php files. I did that. I 've followed the instructions given by Adobe, correctly. Everything is OK with the testing server since my .php files are running. The problem I cannot solve is the following: My main file index.php does not recognize any changes in any external .css file which of course  is declared inside the head section. For example,

```
<link href="mycss/pb.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

where mycss is a folder inside htdocs/tester/ and tester is the folder inside which there are all the site files. There is no error in any path; in case I remove the Apache server everything works fine. There is no error in paths in Dreamweaver Apache setup:

Server Name: Local Apache

Connect using: Local/Network

Server Folder:C:\xampp\htdocs\tester

Web URL: //localhost/tester/
(with http: in the beginning)

However, any change made in pb.css is ignored by index.php!! This is crazy... I suspect this is a matter of php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf, I do not know what. I'd appreciate your help.

Thank you very much

Comment: must be the cache, like Dave said clearing the cache will cause the files to be reloaded

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file is in the correct path.
Also press ctrl+F5 to refresh and clear the cache. Because the css file is stored in the cache of the browser so you don't have to download it each time. It just loads it then.